# Double Linked List Insertion Sorting Bug

Tags: c++, linked-list, insertion-sort

I have implemented an insertion sort in a double link list (highest to lowest) from a file of 10,000 ints, and output to file in reverse order.

To my knowledge I have implemented such a program, however I noticed in the ouput file, a single number is out of place. Every other number is in correct order.

The number out of place is a repeated number, but the other repeats of this number are in correct order. Its just strange how this number is incorrectly placed. Also the unsorted number is only 6 places out of sync.

I have looked through my program for days now with no idea where the problem lies, so I turn to you for help.

Below is the code in question,

(side note: can my question be deleted by myself? rather my colleges dont thieve my code, if not how can it be deleted?)

```
    void DLLIntStorage::insertBefore(int inValue, node *nodeB)
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode = new node();
    newNode->prev = nodeB->prev;
    newNode->next = nodeB;
    newNode->value = inValue;

    if(nodeB->prev==NULL)
    {
        this->front = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        nodeB->prev->next = newNode;
    }
    nodeB->prev = newNode;
}
void DLLIntStorage::insertAfter(int inValue, node *nodeB)
{
    node *newNode;
    newNode = new node();
    newNode->next = nodeB->next;
    newNode->prev = nodeB;
    newNode->value = inValue;

    if(nodeB->next == NULL)
    {
        this->back = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        nodeB->next->prev = newNode;
    }   
    nodeB->next = newNode;
}
void DLLIntStorage::insertFront(int inValue)
{   
    node *newNode;
    if(this->front == NULL)
    {
        newNode = new node();
        this->front = newNode;
        this->back = newNode;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->value = inValue;
    }
    else
    {
        insertBefore(inValue, this->front);
    }

}   
void DLLIntStorage::insertBack(int inValue)
{   
    if(this->back == NULL)
    {
        insertFront(inValue);
    }
    else
    {
        insertAfter(inValue, this->back);
    }
}

ifstream& operator>> (ifstream &in, DLLIntStorage &obj)
{   
    int readInt, counter = 0;               

    while(!in.eof())
    {
        if(counter==dataLength) //stops at 10,000
        {
            break;
        }   

        in >> readInt;

        if(obj.front != NULL )
        {   
            obj.insertion(readInt);         
        }
        else
        {
            obj.insertBack(readInt);
        }
        counter++;
    }       
    return in;
}
void DLLIntStorage::insertion(int inValue)
{
    node* temp;
    temp = this->front;

    if(temp->value >= inValue)
    {
        insertFront(inValue);
        return;
    }
    else
    {       
        while(temp->next!=NULL && temp!=this->back)
        {
            if(temp->value >= inValue)
            {
                insertBefore(inValue, temp);
                return;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    if(temp == this->back)
    {
        insertBack(inValue);
    }
}
```

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: You cannot delete your questions. Completely usual data structures are not often stolen.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I get rather defensive around my code.

Comment: Why not use the Standard Template Library, it is very good.

Comment: If you want people to debug code for you, post something that compiles, along with any input data necessary to demonstrate.  The code you posted does not compile.  DLLIntStorage is not defined.

Comment: I think from the code I've posted its enough for you to understand what is going on, and where it slips up. As I stated the data input is 10,000 integers with only a single node out of place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this part

```
else
{       
    while(temp->next!=NULL && temp!=this->back)
    {
        if(temp->value >= inValue)
        {
            insertBefore(inValue, temp);
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

if(temp == this->back)
{
    insertBack(inValue);
}
```

Imagine what happens if inValue is greater than all values except this->back->value. It gets inserted at the end instead before this->back. By the way, You are inserting equal integers in the reversed order, they are read. For integers it doesn't matter that much, but it could if You inserted other objects. I would change the code of the insertion method to this:

```
node* temp;
temp = this->front;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    if(temp->value > inValue)
    {
        insertBefore(inValue, temp);
        return;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
}
insertBack(inValue);
```

Comment: Cheers, I now understand the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just some remarks.

```
while(!in.eof())
```

This will not stop the inside of the loop from seeing an EOF error. You want

```
while ( in >> readInt )
```

---

Also,

```
if(this->front == NULL)
```

and

```
void DLLIntStorage::insertion(int inValue)
{
    node* temp;
    temp = this->front;

    if(temp->value >= inValue)
```

do not mix. Either the front can be NULL, or it cannot. Likewise, you need to decide whether to use `temp->next!=NULL` or `temp!=this->back`, but not both, as a loop termination condition.

---

My guess would be that some inconsistency between multiple linking conventions is causing the errant value to get pushed into the middle of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on improving the code a little, your points surround the loop termination I will look into. I'm unsure on what multiple linking conventions could be causing the single problem. Thanks.